# how to drop a db2 database that is in an inconsistent state

Tags: db2

I have a DB2 database that suffered a power outage in the storage array, its a test system I just want to kill it and rebuild.

```
db2 connect to mydb
SQL1015N  The database is in an inconsistent state.  SQLSTATE=55025

db2 drop db mydb
SQL1035N  The operation failed because the specified database cannot be
connected to in the mode requested.  SQLSTATE=57019

db2 restart db mydb
SQL1015N  The database is in an inconsistent state.  SQLSTATE=55025

db2stop
SQL1025N  The database manager was not stopped because databases are still active.

db2 backup db mydb to /dev/null
SQL1015N  The database is in an inconsistent state.  SQLSTATE=55025
```

Comment: What's in the diagnostic log when you do `connect` and `restart`? If you don't care about the database, you might as well just uncatalog it and delete its files from the file system.

Answer (score 1):

Since the database seem to be of no value, you can try:

```
db2stop force
ipclean
db2start
db2 drop database mydb
```

You may be interested in the following post/answer. It is not exactly your situation but may be of some help anyhow:

[unable-to-restore-database-because-it-exists-unable-to-drop-because-it-does-not](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/126532/unable-to-restore-database-because-it-exists-unable-to-drop-because-it-does-not/126536#126536)

Comment: Restarting the instance is not going to drop the database though, it will remain in the state it is in.

Comment: @absolutely, but sometimes it helps to clear message queues etc with ipclean, to be able to drop the database